# For-If loop manipulation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to replicate a very simple VBA code on R, to identify duplicates. My goals is to identify how many sets of duplicates in a sample set, first by reading down across rows, then reading across column.
So I came up with this piece of sample:

```
x<-matrix(data=c("Ali","Ali","Abu","Ali","Ahmad","siti","Ali","Abu", "Ahmad", "Ali", "Abu", "Aisyah", "Khalid", "Robin","Ahmad","Ali","JOrdan","siti"), nrow=6)
x<-data.frame(x)

colnames(x)<-c("nama1","nama2","nama3")
```

so you would get something like this

```
 nama1  nama2  nama3
1   Ali    Ali Khalid
2   Ali    Abu  Robin
3   Abu  Ahmad  Ahmad
4   Ali    Ali    Ali
5 Ahmad    Abu JOrdan
6  siti Aisyah   siti
```

So what I want to do is essentially:

```
c<-0
for (i in x){
    if (x[i,1]==x[i+1,1]){
        c=c+1
        }
    print c
    }
```

The final output I want is to specify how many duplicates are there in each row, and subsequently do it across the column... like

```
 for i=1 to 10
 for j=1 to 20
        cells(i,j)="XXX"
        do this
 next j
 next i
```

problem is I don't know how to specify individual cell in R like eg. in VBA you can do cells(i+1,1)=cells(i,1).. and I am learning to do very simple data manipulation in R.

I would like to sum up the c value for all the columns at the end. So it would be 4+4+6= 14.

Any advice is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Can you show how would your expected output look like?

Comment: Agree with Ronak, you should explicitly show your expected output. Perhaps something like `apply(x, 1, function(i) sum(duplicated(i)))` (for the rows) and `apply(x, 2, function(i) sum(duplicated(i)))` (for the columns) might be what you're after

Comment: Hi guys sorry for the delay I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#row total number of duplicates
apply(x, 1, function(x) length( x[ duplicated(x) ] ) )
#[1] 1 0 1 2 0 1

#column total number of duplicates
apply(x, 2, function(x) length( x[ duplicated(x) ] ) )
#nama1 nama2 nama3 
#    2     2     0
```

Comment: This is not code-golfing but `apply(x, 1, function(i) sum(duplicated(i)))` is slightly shorter (see my comment above;-)

Comment: @MauritsEvers true :)